# Get the signal level in the API Java sound

Tags: java, audio, wav, javasound

I'm reading a sound with the API JAVA sound and I'd like to recover the signal level. I have no problem to read the file and here is the code I use to try to get the signal level :

```
for (byte bit:bytes) {
        if (i<2) {
            signalLevelLeft=signalLevelLeft+Math.abs(bit);
            System.out.println("Left : "+i+" - "+bit);
            i++;
        } else if (2<=i && i<3) {
            signalLevelRight=signalLevelRight+Math.abs(bit);
            //System.out.println("Right : "+i+" - "+bit);
            i++;
        } else if (i==3) {
            signalLevelRight=signalLevelRight+Math.abs(bit);
            //System.out.println("Right : "+i+" - "+bit);
            i=0;
        }


        if (signalLevelLeft>maxLeft) {
            maxLeft= signalLevelLeft;
            System.out.println("Max left : " + maxLeft);
        }
```

After I get the audioInputStream, the format, the line, opened the line (..), here is the code I use to read the sound and feed the method seen just above :

```
    try {
    byte bytes[] = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead=0;
    while (((bytesRead = audioInputStream.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length)) != -1) && !stop) {
        line.write(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
    }
} catch (IOException io) {
    io.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
```

To test the signal level, I generated a squared signal only on the left channel with audacity and I read it with my code (beware if you do it, this sound is really ugly). Here are the results : 
On the right channel it is perfect, the signal is 0 everywhere :

Right : 2 - 0

Right : 3 - 0

Right : 2 - 2

Right : 3 - 0 (...)

On the left channel, I have this strange result :

Left : 0 - 0

Left : 1 - -128

Left : 0 - 1

Left : 1 - -128 (...)

Left : 0 - -1

Left : 1 - 127

Left : 0 - -1

Left : 1 - 127

Why do I have those 0 on the left channel ? As I have a squared signal, I thought I would vave this kind of result :

Left : 0 - -128

Left : 1 - -128

Left : 0 - -128

Left : 1 - -128 (...)

Left : 0 - 127

Left : 1 - 127

Left : 0 - 127

Left : 1 - 127

Of course, I have the same kind of strange result with a right only signal and even with a stereo signal : It seems that only 1 information on 2 carry the signal. I also checked with a maximum zoom on Audacity and it's really a squared signal with any 0...

Thank you for your answers and have a great day.

Comment: Did you assemble the bytes into PCM before squaring? What is the format of the sound encoding?

Comment: When I create the sound file in Audacity, I just go into the menu Generate, then Sound then I choose a "squarred wave" at 440 Hz frequency with a maximum range of 1 (0 to 1). When it's done, I save the sound as a WAV file PCM signed 16 bits.

Comment: That means it takes two bytes per PCM value. You might be able to make better sense of the results if you assemble the bytes into the PCM values they represent.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally go the answer (with the tip of Phil, thank you...). You are right, there are 2 bytes, in little endian mode per PCM value. So I had to catch the two first bytes, shift the second one to 8 bits on the left with that kind of sign : ">>" and then, add the second byte.
The result of this addition (should I say concatenation ?) of the 2 bytes is the PCM value.

I tested it with sinusoidal and squarred signals and the results are ok : I got the value expected.

Here is the code I used :

```
byte b1, b2, b3, b4;
for (byte octet : bytes) {
        if (i==1) {
            //Gauche
            b1=octet;
            //System.out.println(i+" *** "+bit);
            i++;
        } else if (i==2) {
            b2=octet;
            //Gauche
            if (Math.abs((b2<<8)+b1)> signalLevelLeft) {
                signalLevelLeft=Math.abs((b2<<8)+b1);
                //c2=Math.abs((b2<<8)+b1);
                //System.out.println("Gauche : "+c2);
            }               
            i++;
        } else if (i==3) {
            //Droite
            b3=octet;
            //System.out.println(i+" *** "+bit);
            i++;
        } else if (i==4) {
            //Droite
            b4=octet;
            if (Math.abs((b4<<8)+b3)>signalLevelRight) {
                signalLevelRight=Math.abs((b4<<8)+b3);
                //c4=Math.abs((b4<<8)+b3);
                //System.out.println("Droite : "+c4);
            }               
            i=1;
        }
}
```

Have a great day to all...